# Equalizer for iPad?

Tags: recommendations

Apologies in advance if this question is not appropriate for this SE. I didn't find another SE that is more appropriate, nor did I find the questions scope for Sound Design SE. If this question is not appropriate, can you please suggest a good place to ask?

I am using an iPad with Pandora and M-Audio Studiophile AV 40 speakers. It sounds good, but boomy.

I want run an equalizer, but apparently it is not possible to use an equalizer on iPad with any apps besides iTunes.

Is there a way to use an equalizer with an iPad with apps such as Pandora? Is there a recommended hardware equalizer or other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, if the app you're playing music from does not have a built-in equalizer then you're out of luck so you'll have to insert an equalizer in your signal chain somewhere between the iPad and your monitors. This could be a hardware equalizer or software you run with an audio I/O on another device.

As for suggestions for a hardware EQ it really depends on what else you might want to do with it. If it's just for music playback and not critical listening / mixing etc. then you can just go through a consumer "hifi" EQ.

Be aware that the boomy sound can also be the result of where you placed your speakers, don't place them too close to a wall, not in corners, isolate them from whatever they're standing on etc.

You can also cut out a bit of acoustic / dense foam to close up the bass reflex port.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what André says, you could try 'Audiobus' it's a signal router for iOS that allows you to route synths etc. to other apps (Moog filter app or multitrack recorder apps). But I'm not sure if your app, that you use to play music with on your ipad, is compliant with the 'Audiobus' protocol. Figure that out and maybe you have a change.

http://audiob.us/

Good luck